# How to determine file type from MVC-like URL

Tags: php, magento

I want to add an audio player to product view page of a Magento store for playing sample audio files, so I edited `magento_root/app/design/path/to/theme/template/downloadable/catalog/product/samples.phtml` to this.

```
<?php if ($this->hasSamples()): ?>
 <dl class="item-options">
    <dt><?php echo $this->getSamplesTitle() ?></dt>
    <?php $_samples = $this->getSamples() ?>
    <?php foreach ($_samples as $_sample): ?>
        <dd>
            <!--HTML5 Audio player-->
            <audio controls>
                <source src="<?php echo $this->getSampleUrl($_sample) ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
            <br/>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getSampleUrl($_sample) ?>" <?php echo $this->getIsOpenInNewWindow() ? 'onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'"' : ''; ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_sample->getTitle()); ?></a>
        </dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </dl>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This works fine but i want the player to show only for audio files. My problem is that the URL returned by `$this->getSampleUrl($_sample)` is of the form 
http://example.com/index.php/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/1/ with no information about the file type on the URL.

I considered fetching the content of the URL to determine the file type but I feel it will be silly to completely read a file just to determine its type.
Tried `pathinfo()` but it returns nothing about the file type.

I want to achieve something like this

```
$sample_file = $this->getSampleUrl($_sample);
$type = getFileType($sample_file);
if(preg_match('audio-file-type-pattern',$type){ ?>
 <!--HTML5 Audio player-->
 <audio controls>
   <source src="<?php echo $sample_file ?>" type="<?php echo $type?>">
   Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try sending a HEAD request with curl. With a HEAD request you are just getting the headers and not the body (in your case the audio file):

```
<?php

$url = 'http://domain.com/index.php/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/1/';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);

// Only calling the head
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); // header will be at output
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);


$content = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);


echo $content;

//Outputs:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 01 Apr 2016 16:56:42 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.12
Last-Modified: Wed, 07 Oct 2015 18:23:27 GMT
ETag: "8d416d3-8b77a-52187d7bc49d1"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 571258
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
```

With a simple regular expression you can get the file's Content-Type:

```
preg_match('/Content\-Type: ([\w\/]+)/', $content, $m);

echo print_r($m,1);

//Outputs:
Array
(
     [0] => Content-Type: audio/mpeg
     [1] => audio/mpeg
)
```